# Angular 2 MDF validator to require atleast one of two fields

Tags: validation, angular, mdf

I have two input fields: email and phone, if user enters input in email then phone input is not required and vice versa. Atleast one of the fields is required at a time. I have model driven form and I am trying to write a custom validator function for this. So far I have got: 
In my `validator.ts`:

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function requiredOptional(emailVal: string, phoneVal: string) {
  return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    let email = group.controls[emailVal];
    let phone = group.controls[phoneVal];

    if (!email.value|| !phone.value) {
      return {
        isRequired: true
      };
    }
  }
}
```

In my `testForm.component.ts`:

```
export class TestFormComponent{
 testForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.testForm= fb.group({
    email: ['', emailValidator],
    phone: ['', phoneValidator],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
  }, {validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword')},
    {validator: requiredOptional('email', 'phone')}
  )
  }
  onSubmit(value: Object): void {
  console.log(value);
}
}
```

and in my `testForm.component.html`:

```
    <form [formGroup]="testForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="testForm.valid && onSubmit(testForm.value)">
    .......
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" formControlName="email">
                <div class="form-text error" *ngIf="testForm.controls.email.touched">
                  <div *ngIf="testForm.hasError('isRequired')">Email or Phone is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="testForm.controls.email.hasError('invalidEmail')">Email is invalid.</div>
                </div>
    .......
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number*" formControlName="phone">
                <div class="form-text error" *ngIf="testForm.controls.phone.touched">

                  <div *ngIf="testForm.hasError('isRequired')">Email or Phone is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="testForm.controls.phone.hasError('invalidPhone')">Phone is invalid.</div>
                </div>
.......
<button [disabled]="!testForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Sign up</button>
        </form>
```

But this is not working, I am getting error in `testForm.component.ts: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call targets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple validating functions by composing like following:

```
export class TestFormComponent{
 testForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.testForm= fb.group({
    email: ['', emailValidator],
    phone: ['', phoneValidator],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
  }, {validator: Validators.compose([matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword'), requiredOptional('email', 'phone')]})
  }
  onSubmit(value: Object): void {
  console.log(value);
}
}
```

Focus on following change:

```
{validator: Validators.compose([matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword'), requiredOptional('email', 'phone')]}
```

Instead of setting matchingPasswords validator, we can set array of validating functions by using Validators.compose